# Using Boost zip_iterator to write two vectors to CSV file

Tags: c++, c++03, boost-iterators

I've got two vectors that I'd like to write to file in CSV form. I can do this "by hand" using a for-loop but I'm taking stab at using boost zip_iterator, for the first time ever. This is how far I've been able to come. ([online version](http://rextester.com/TAWART20616))

*Please note that this for a legacy project and therefore I cannot use newer versions of C++ (e.g. C++11, C++14, C++17)*

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

typedef boost::tuples::tuple<unsigned,unsigned> DataPair;
typedef std::ostream_iterator<DataPair> DataPairOStream;

// Error messages suggest that something resembling this overload might be needed.
// This however does not solve the problem.
DataPairOStream& operator<<( DataPairOStream& stream , const DataPair& )
{
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned> data1( 10 , 1 );
    std::vector<unsigned> data2( 10 , 2 );

    std::ofstream outputFile( "Foo.txt" );
    DataPairOStream outputIterator( outputFile , "\n" );   // ???

    std::copy(
        boost::make_zip_iterator( boost::make_tuple( data1.begin() , data2.begin() ) ) ,
        boost::make_zip_iterator( boost::make_tuple( data1.end()   , data2.end()   ) ) ,
        outputIterator ); 
}
```

Snippet of the error message (the entire thing is simply too long to paste)

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/include/c++/bits/stream_iterator.h:198:13: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int> >::ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const boost::tuples::tuple<unsigned int, unsigned int>’)
  *_M_stream << __value;
  ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why don't boost tuple operator == and << compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702425/why-dont-boost-tuple-operator-and-compile)

Comment: I don't think so. This question is about writing pairs of vectors to a file. The answer to both questions may be to provide an implementation for an overload but that's where the similarity ends.

Comment: The problem is the exactly the same, so is the solution: `#include "boost/tuple/tuple_io.hpp"` which already provides the overload.

Comment: @O'Neil Thanks for bringing `tuple_io` to my attention. I've looked it up (found this https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.tuple) but have no idea how to use it in this problem. 'Still new to these libraries.

Comment: Its inclusion is enough to make your code work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work good. Now ADL finds the `operator<<` overload because it is put in namespace `boost::tuples`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

typedef boost::tuples::tuple<unsigned,unsigned> DataPair;

namespace boost{
namespace tuples{

std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream& stream , const DataPair& )
{
    return stream;
}

}
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned> data1( 10 , 1 );
    std::vector<unsigned> data2( 10 , 2 );

    std::ofstream outputFile( "Foo.txt" );
    std::ostream_iterator<DataPair> outputIterator( outputFile , "\n" ); 

    std::copy(
        boost::make_zip_iterator( boost::make_tuple( data1.begin() , data2.begin() ) ) ,
        boost::make_zip_iterator( boost::make_tuple( data1.end()   , data2.end()   ) ) ,
        outputIterator ); 
}
```

In practice putting `operator <<` in `std` also worked, but it **should NOT** be done because it is **undefined behaviour**.

Answer (score 1):

`DataPairOStream` is an *iterator* not a *stream*. It **adapts** a `std::ostream` to the iterator interface.

You need to define

```
std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & os, const DataPair & dp)
{
    return os << boost::tuples::get<0>(dp) << boost::tuples::get<1>(dp);
}
```

Comment: ADL won't find it in the global namespace.